# Linear regression with weekly spending data

Tags: least-squares

I want to make a linear regression where the dependent variable is the amount spent on some good and the independent variables are some characteristics of the consumer (age, gender, wage, etc). Specifically, I want to know how much this characteristics influence the annual spending on this good.

But the way that the survey was made is asking how much was spent on the good in the week of reference. So a lot of zero consumption was recorded (more than 90% of the records are zero). So, every regression that I make to explain the spending as a function of the consumer characteristics have no significance. What is expected if the good has some sporadic way of being consumed.

Is there any work around for this problem?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  "in the good" = ?

Comment: Sorry, rolando. English is not my first language.

Comment: No apology necessary, Rene, I was just trying to get the meaning straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for this kind of problem, where there is a lot of zeros because the consumption is somewhat rare. It is a Sample Selection Model (a.k.a Heckman correction or heckit model).

First, you do a probit model in the whole data set to find the chance that the interviewed have consumed the good based on their characteristics:

$$    \mathrm{prob}(y_i>0)=\Phi(\boldsymbol{X_i} \frac{\boldsymbol{\beta}}{\sigma})    $$
where:

$\Phi$ is the normal cumulative distribution, $\boldsymbol{X_i}$ is the vector of the consumer characteristics, $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ is the coefficients vector, and ${\sigma}$ is the standard deviation of the error of the latent variable.

Second, you calculate the inverse Mills ratio term for all observations.

Third, you estimate the consumption equation using OLS with the inverse Mills ratio as an explanatory variable for observations with positive consumption.

$$ \boldsymbol{y}=\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{u}    $$

This [document](http://www.ualberta.ca/~bhumphre/class/zeros_v1.pdf) present a lot of approaches to solve the problems of zeros in microeconomic regressions.

See also this wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Mills_ratio).

Comment: Identification will be fragile if you don't have an exclusion restriction-a variable that changes the extensive margin of participation/purchase, but not the intensive margin of how much to spend. Otherwise, if $X$ in the second equation is just $X$ in the first part plus the IMR, the identification comes solely from the non-linearity of the IMR and it will be weak. A two-part model might be worth considering if you don't have an exclusion restriction.

Comment: Good point @DimitriyV.Masterov. In my case I will use the spending in concurrent goods to estimate the probability that the user purchased the good. I hope this will work.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you have an inappropriate survey for the question you're trying to answer.

If this survey was conducted over multiple weeks then I suppose you could aggregate the data to infer the annual spending, however I think your best bet is to just find another data source that tells you the annual spending.